# Publishing facebook app linked to iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, publishing

I have an iOS game (actionscript 3, air, Facebook-ANE from Freshplanet) and I use the Facebook graph API to keep the game score. Everything works like a charm. The problem comes when I try to publish the linked facebook app - it requires the iOS app id (for iPhone and iPad), which I can't have before making the iOS live in AppStore, but I also can't push the iOS live before having the Facebook app available.

Guess I'm missing something.

For the record - I use Facebook only for the scoring, the game isn't available on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the App ID when you create the app in iTunesConnect, before you submit the app.

Comment: That's true, but the Facebook doesn't save the App ID unless it is live in the AppStore (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the solution is just to put iPad/iPhone IDs to 0, publish the facebook app, then publish iOS, then go back to Facebook and change the app Id.